# Route FTP Traffic via 2nd Ethernet Port in Centos

Tags: networking, centos, routing, ftp, cloudlinux

This is my first post and at this stage is research, I run a server that uses a 1gb ethernet port and trunk, the data limit on this is 1TB (either upload or download) a month, i'm doing offsite FTP backups and can see this is daily reaching 13GB. I'm worried this is going to contribute to me breaching my monthly allowance, so I'm considering taking out a second port on a 100MB trunk (which is unmetered) for the FTP traffic specifically.

I'm just not sure how to pass the correct traffic to that port, the physical machine is a Xenserver 7, and the VM that I want to use multiple ports on is Cloudlinux 7 (Centos 7 Variant).

I haven't purchased the cable yet but need to find out if this is possible. I can request that the other cable is on a different subnet to make this easier. I'm not sure what else anyone needs to help me with this.

Thank for you time.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  I would use `ip route` to test a route statement to send traffic down that interface to it's gateway.  Once you confirm it is good, you would want to persist the route in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts using the [RHEL7 networking guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Using_the_Command_Line_Interface.html#sec-Static-Routes_and_the_Default_Gateway)   It should not matter if this is a physical or virtual host.  You can have more than 1 gateway and IP.  Your enginnering team or provider can help.

Comment: Okay, I haven't tried anything yet as I didn't want to purchase the second port/cable (nearly £40 a month) until I have the process down. At the moment its just me managing the server and such, but the datacentre can help me with the gateway addressing and such. Its a big learning curve for me this, but I'll rather do it right now and not have to sort it later.

Comment: You could probably spin up some VM's on your laptop and simulate this configuration, but your time spent vs. the cost of the cable may be a wash.